# Invalid parameter for cross validation estimator. value error

Tags: python

I  write a code for Parameter tuning in Svc. I  use three different values for gama. But i run the code, it says that the parameter isn't ok for using here and it asks for:

```
 Invalid parameter gamma for estimator LogisticRegression. Check the list of available parameters with estimator.get_params().keys().
```

here is the part of my code:

```
folds=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=10)

hyper_params = [ {'gama': [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [5,10]}]

model=SVC(kernel="rbf")

model_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = hyper_params, scoring= 'accuracy', cv = folds, verbose = 1, return_train_score=True)

model_cv.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I use this code for Mnist Dataset in csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message, you are using invalid parameters and you can use the function estimator.get_params().keys() to see all available parameters for your estimator. But as I already code something like this, it seems your parameters to be ok. I have found a syntax error: your write "gama" as a key in your dictionary but the correct form is "gamma". So, you missed an 'm'. your code should be:

```
….
hyper_params = [ {'gamma': [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [5,10]}]
…..
```

You most probably will be fine. But if it doesn’t solve your problem, try to change your gamma parameters.